# Azure Web Job: System.NotSupportedException - Unsupported invocation type ''

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I'm having a bizarre issue whereby my web job continues to fail at intermittent intervals.

Just to give a brief overview of the current process, my web job is tied to a queue trigger from which a custom object is obtained:

```
public async Task ProcessClientUsageQueueMessage(
        [QueueTrigger("clientusageupdated")] ClientUsage clientUsageMessage,
        TextWriter log)
    {
        log.WriteLine("Message received: {0}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clientUsageMessage));

        var clientReference = clientUsageMessage.ClientReference;
        await ProcessClientUsage(clientReference, log);
    }
```

ProcessClientUsage then goes on to query data from an on-premises SQL server via a hybrid connection. The stored procedure unfortunately has to sift through large amounts of data resulting in this call sometimes taking around 10 minutes to complete.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ClientUsageDetail>> GetClientUsage(Client client)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(client.ClientDatabaseConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand { CommandText = "[Oracle].[_GetUsage]", Connection = connection, CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, CommandTimeout = 2000 })
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@KeepForDays", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = client.DaysRetention ?? 40 });
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@LatestEventDetailID", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.BigInt, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = client.LatestEventDetailId ?? 0 });
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                var results = await reader.ReadAsIEnumarableAsync<ClientUsageDetail>();
                _log.Debug("ClientUsageRepository.GetClientUsage: Client: {0}, results: {1}", client.Reference, results.Count());
                return results;
            }
        }
    }
```

However while the web job is making the call (and occasionally when re-starting the web job), the following exception is thrown and the web job dies / restarts:

System.NotSupportedException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.dll
Additional information: Unsupported invocation type ''.

This happens both locally when debugging the web job as well as on azure where the web job is hosted on a site with a standard service plan with 'Always On' set to true.

Is this due to some timeout that is occurring within the continuous web job, or perhaps an issue with an incoming queue message? I've tried re-creating the queue and manually posting a single message, but I noticed that after a couple of minutes the web job responds to another message (which I didn't create).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Not sure if it's relevant, however in the interest of full disclosure I also have Azure table storage and Redis cache instances instantiated via dependency injection (StructureMap) which are used later in the process to persist / load the results.

Comment: Same as [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7cdb3052-da11-4bfa-80b8-b4f70339a53b/continuous-web-job-systemnotsupportedexception-unsupported-invocation-type-?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview). Best to keep in one place to avoid duplicate investigations.

Comment: I believe that this may have actually been an issue with my project setup at the time.

Since having recreated the project with the latest nuget package versions everything seems to be working as expected.

Thanks for your help!